# Making rest request with Oauth

Tags: apex, webservices, authentication, oauth, pagereference

I have all four Oauth token **consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessKey and accessSecret**. I need to make a request to a **url** from my apex code. Is there any library or a way to make this request. In java I did this using SignPost and HttpClient libraries. Is there any signpost library equivalent in apex/salesforce ?

Comment: Look into the documentation for HTTPRequest/HTTP/HTTPResponse it will get you what you need

Comment: Anyone has a page reference library example which does the same?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What do you need to do?

Comment: I have used these 4 oauth tokens in java to make http rest request to a url. This is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146670/use-signpost-java-library-or-equivalent-in-saleforce-apex-code how i used used them. I used signpost library. Its working. I need to write this code block in apex. I have also tried what keith suggested in answer. But I couldn't figure out the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Apex has pretty good APIs that are the equivalent of a Java HttpClient. You need to check the URLs and parameter names carefully for various implementations of OATH and related APIs. Here's what getting the email address from Facebook after you've got the access token might look  like:

```
public String accessTokenToEmail(String accessToken) {

     PageReference pr = new PageReference('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token');
     pr.getParameters().put('fields', 'email');
     pr.getParameters().put('access_token', accessToken);

     String body = httpGet(pr);
     return extractJsonField(body, 'email');
 }
 private String httpGet(PageReference pr) {

     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setEndpoint(pr.getUrl());
     req.setMethod('GET');
     req.setTimeout(60 * 1000);

     HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
     return res.getBody();
}
private String extractJsonField(String body, String field) {

    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(body);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME
                && parser.getText() == field) {
            parser.nextToken();
            return parser.getText();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You will also need to add a [Remote Site Setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&language=en) for each domain that you want to access e.g. "https://graph.facebook.com".

Comment: Can you please give an example on how to use oauth tokens in apex. In Java using signpost library, this is how we do `OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey,consumerSecret);
consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken,accessTokenSecret);HttpPost req= new HttpPost(url);
consumer.sign(req);`. I can't find a example of PageReference doing the same. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the apex code how to get an access token for a Salesforce org:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

request.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');  // sfdc sandbox
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setTimeout(60000);

String consumerKey = '...';
String consumerSecret  = '...';
String accessKey = '...';
String accessSecret = '...';

request.setBody(
    'grant_type=password' +
    '&client_id=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(consumerKey, 'UTF-8') +
    '&client_secret=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(consumerSecret, 'UTF-8') +
    '&username=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(accessKey, 'UTF-8') +
    '&password=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(accessSecret, 'UTF-8')
);

HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
System.debug(response.getBody());
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. I think request body will be different. Getting 401 error. tokens are correct because same tokens are working at java code.

Answer (score 0):

Above Code works perfectly, thanks for that!
Encoding the client data was key for my solution, all examples in the world skip this important "detail". Our username had a "+" inside, without encoding we always got "400 bad request".